# How to prevent users from bypassing or closing out of data validation message alert, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a data validation in google sheets, that when a user scans the barcode, it pops up that it is not in the store. However, after it pops up (if they don't look at their screen) it automatically closes. I need it to prevent the message from closing, thus preventing them to  continue and see the issue until it is resolved. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in google sheets, but there is an option of rejecting the input if it does not matches your criteria. Moreover you can show a validation help text, so that you can also have a warning to the user.